# IIF for Using as Connection type

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a program which depending on the client it will use either a SQL Server connection or Oracle connection. 
Instead of writing two different (similar) functions one for Oracle and one for SQL Server, I am trying to create my "Using" statements combined and have the system to choose which one to choose depending on what type of database connection is being used.

The pseudo-code which I'm trying to achieve is:

```
IIF(database=Oracle,   Using connection As New OracleConnection(SettingsConnection.conString), 
  Using connection As New SQLConnection(SettingsConnection.conString))
```

Is there a way to make the "Using" statement work this way? Should I create two different functions, or simply to have two big if/else i.e. `if oracle = true //create oracle statements else if SQLServer = true //create SQLServer statements?`

Comment: ADO.NET *already* allows you to [abstract the different providers and connections using only configuration settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z(v=vs.110).aspx) and create abstract DbConnection, DbCommand objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could abstract getting the connection to another method:

```vb
Using connection as DbConnection = GetConnection(database)
    '...
End Using
```

```vb
Function GetConnection(database as String) as DbConnection
    If database = "Oracle" Then
        Return New OracleConnection(...)
    Else
        Return New SqlConnection(...)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I believe it should be    Using connection = GetConnection

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Sub InsertIncentiveNote(MyConnection As String, xxx As Integer, xxxx As String)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(IIf(MyConnection = "G", My.Settings.usgeContracts_Two_Conx, My.Settings.usgeContracts_One_Conx))
        Using command As New SqlCommand("dbo.xxx_Insert", connection)
```

Comment: This is passing different arguments to the same constructor, as opposed to constructing two entirely different types

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of the framework, you can use the If function instead. Iif is a standard function where both the true and false parts are evaluated. This leads to creating a connection object that is abandoned without its Dispose method being called (tying up underylying connections until a GC is called). You could also cast your connection to the generic IDbConnection interface as that is a common interface between the two data providers.

```
Using connection = Ctype(If(database = Oracle, 
                            New OracleConnection(SettingsConnection.conString),
                            New SQLConnection(SettingsConnection.conString))),
                         System.Data.IDbConnection)
```

After that, you should the connection object to create any transactions and commands.

```
Using cmd = connection.CreateCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "My Command"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```